# Flair reputation lower than profile rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Why does my rep appear lower in the Super User flair than it does on my profile?

Here is my image to prove it:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help me as I don't know how to fix it.

I was also thinking could it be a bug in Super User since I have other accounts on Stack Overflow but they're only at 1 rep. Also my badge count is different.

Comment: What is your rep as stated on http://superuser.com/reputation ?

Comment: 361 but I went down

Comment: Now I am up to 384

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reputation flair is cached and may lag 24-48 hours behind your actual rep.

edit: looks correct to me.

https://superuser.com/users/40027 says 179 rep and...

[image]

Comment: Incorrect, it says 1 to me @Jeff ;-)